# Add row from code in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

Hi I have trouble with adding `TableRow` with `TextView` and button from code. I read a lot of answers on StackOverflow but still didn't work. My main goal is set weight for textview and button but after click on button here is zero action. Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.zawadeusz.to_do_list.List_Activity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" >


        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/Table">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="TEXT"
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_weight=".9" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="DONE"
                    android:layout_weight=".1"
                    android:id="@+id/DoneBtn"
                    android:layout_column="12"
                    android:onClick="Done"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my java code:

```
public class List_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView TaskTextView;
    Button DoneBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        DoneBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DoneBtn);
        TaskTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String message = intent.getStringExtra("TASK");

        TaskTextView.setText(message);
    }

    public void Done(View view)
    {
        TableLayout tbl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.Table);

        TableLayout.LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1.0f);
        TableLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,.9f);
        TableLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,.1f);

        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        TextView task = new TextView(this);
        Button done = new Button(this);

        row.setLayoutParams(params);
        task.setLayoutParams(params1);
        done.setLayoutParams(params2);


        task.setText("Textview");
        done.setText("Button");

        row.addView(task);
        row.addView(done);
        tbl.addView(row);

    }
}
```

Comment: if you put a debug print as the first line of `public void Done`, does that get printed?

Comment: yes, i used Toast for that and when i delete params1 and params2 then this method works but without weights and its looks terrible